# Apply css style of one class into another class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For the  below bootstrap code, I have to hard code col-sm-2 and col-sm-10 to all my form elements. 
Is there a way where  i can  avoid this hardcode and use x-col-sm-left and x-col-sm-right based on below logic?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="x-col-sm-left control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="x-col-sm-right">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="x-col-sm-left control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="x-col-sm-right">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>

x-col-sm-left {
 extend col-sm-2 (for example)
}
x-col-sm-right{
 extend col-sm-10 (for example)
}
```

Lets say later I need to change col-sm-2 to col-sm-3, I should be able to do this change as below wihtout editing my html code

```
x-col-sm-left {
     extend col-sm-3 (for example)
    }
    x-col-sm-right{
     extend col-sm-9 (for example)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand you completely but i think this is what you mean.

So add a class which will only be applied within another class you would do the folowing

```
.col-sm-2 .x-col-sm-left {
   /*Style you want here*/
}
```

so now x-col-sm-left can be used in col-sm-2 once you have a parent of col-sm-2.. this will overwrite

```
.col-sm-2{
  /*Syle*/
}
```

as for inheritance, you can use the `,` do define multiple classes with the same attributes.. But there is no direct `inherits // extends` in CSS that i am aware of.

Example of multiple definition :

```
.col-sm-2, .x-col-sm-left {
       /*Style you want here*/
    }
```

Comment: not looking for div styles applied for inner class. I am looking for style inheritance (Sort of)

Comment: @faiz im not aware of anything that could offer `extends` style inheritance.. but I have updated the answer with a best attempt